# How to create and run a Pod with the Kubernetes Java API?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I want to create a pod and I also want to execute some commands inside the pod/job
as you can see in the argument  `POST 'http://localhost:4009/src/getEndpount` I'm just seeing that the job is created in the console `kubectl get jobs -A`, but I am not able to see what is going on inside the job or if the Pod is created. I didn't see any pods for this job `created kubectl get pods`.

```
    fun newJob(uuid: String, githubURL: String?, token: String): V1Job? {
        val respondToEndpoint = String.format("%s%s%s", backendUrl, REST_API_BASE_PATH, uuid)
    
        return V1JobBuilder()
          .withNewMetadata()
          .withName(uuid.toString())
          .endMetadata()
          .withNewSpec()
          .withActiveDeadlineSeconds(120)
          .withParallelism(1)
          .withNewTemplate().withNewSpec()
          .addNewImagePullSecret()
          .withName(imagePullSecret)
          .endImagePullSecret()
          .withRestartPolicy("Never")
          .addNewContainer()
          .withName(uuid)
          .withImage(analystImage)
          .withImagePullPolicy("Always")
          .addToCommand("/bin/sh", "-c")
          .addToArgs(
            String.format(
              // "git clone %s /tmp/code && cd /tmp/code && r=$(/opt/tools/bin/sca_bom.sh $(pwd) $(git rev-parse HEAD) run 2>/dev/null) && curl --location --request PATCH '%s' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'token: %s' --data-raw \"\$r\"",
              "curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4009/src/getEndpount' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -H 'token: %s' --data-raw \"\$r\"",
              token
            )
          )
          .endContainer().endSpec().endTemplate().endSpec()
          

   .build()
   }
```

After the job creation I do a nameSpace creation with the next code,

```
  val job: V1Job? = kubeClient.newJob(uuid, repoURL, token)
  batchV1Api.createNamespacedJob(namespace, job, null, null, "", "")
```

My question is if the `createNamespacedJob` method from the batchV1Api, I am running or creating some Pods, I can't see too much info regarding what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the kubernetes-client Java SDK Doc Here [createNamespacedJob](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#createNamespacedJob)

It returns an V1Job that contains some info you may need.

If it was not enough for you, you can try [readNamespacedJob](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md#readNamespacedJob)